# how to use glDrawPixels to render a picture as a background

Tags: opengl, textures, texture-mapping, gldrawpixels

Here is the thing: I want to load a picture as a background filled in the whole viewport. This background should always face to the camera no matter where the camera face to. 
First I naturally think use a texture as a background, my code is below:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0,1,0,1,0,1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, myimage.GetID());
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2f(0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2f(1, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex2f(1, 1);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex2f(0, 1);
glEnd();

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPopMatrix();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Believe me, myimage is a CIMAGE class that can load pics into textures, it works well.
However, for some unknown reason, my application cannot load a texture into a rectangle. (I described this problem here [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698522/why-cannot-load-texture-into-my-app)) As a result, I only can see a rectangle frame around my viewport.

So, I figure out another solution.

I use the glDrawPixels instead of a texture. My code is below:

```
glRasterPos2i(0, 0);
glDrawPixels(myimage.GetWidth(), myimage.GetHeight(), (myimage.GetBPP() == 24)?GL_RGB:GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
    myimage.GetData());
```

The picture appeared! However, the pic didn't always face to my camera. It only appears in a particular direction. You know, like a object in the scene, but not a background always face to the camera.

So anybody know how to use the glDrawPixels to implement a background?

By the way, I think this background is not a object placed in the 3D scene. So billboards may not be my solution. Again, this background filled in the whole view port and always face to camera.

Comment: What is the width/height of the picture you're loading?

Comment: I guess `glDrawPixels` tries to use the current raster position (which is affected by the usual transformation pipeline). But whatever, just don't use `glDrawPixels` instead of a textured quad. Rather fix your texturing code, maybe as ananthonline suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the reasons your texture loading might not work is because it might not have power-of-two dimensions. Try a square 256x256 texture (or the like) to see if this is the problem. Look here for more info on [Rectangle Textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rectangle_Texture).

Coming back to your background issue - the right way to do this would be to

1. Set up an orthographic projection/viewport that fills the entire screen.

   ```
   glViewport(0,0,nw,nh);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho(0,1,0,1,0,1);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   ```
2. Disable depth testing
3. Draw the fullscreen quad with the texture/texture rectangle you have loaded.

   ```
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
   glVertex2f(0,0);
   glVertex2f(1,0);
   glVertex2f(1,1);
   glVertex2f(0,1);
   glEnd();
   ```
4. Set up your regular projection/modelview and continue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks anantholine, you're very nice. But unfortunately, the size of my picture is 512X512. I think it's a pow-of-two dimension. And what makes me frustrated is this picture can be loaded as a texture in another small project(NeHe tut.5). What's worse, my project originally loaded some texture, it works well. But I loaded picture in the same way, I failed. Could you please give me another hint about my problem?